# It is safe to use allowUnlimitedContractSize: true?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, hardhat, error, hardhat-deploy

I'm trying to deploy with Hardhat a Smart Contract which has too much code, even after refactoring and using libraries. The only solution would be a total refactor following the diamond pattern, or something like that.

When compiling I see the warning:

> `Warning: Contract code size exceeds 24576 bytes (a limit introduced in`
> `Spurious Dragon). This contract may not be deployable on mainnet.`
> `Consider enabling the optimizer (with a low "runs" value!), turning`
> `off revert strings, or using libraries.`

And when trying to deploy, transaction reverts with the following error:

> `Error: Transaction reverted: trying to deploy a contract whose code is too large`

I have found an interesting alternative in the networks setting,  in `hardhat.config.ts` file, setting the `allowUnlimitedContractSize` property to `true`.

```
    networks: {
        hardhat: {
          allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,
          url: "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/",
          chainId: chainIds.bscMainnet,
          
        },
```

My biggest concern is: How safe it is using this approach to deploy Smart Contracts that would throw an error ?

And if it is a safe practice. Why bother about contract size, having the option of setting `allowUnlimitedContractSize` to `true`

Answer (score 1):

[EIP-170](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-170) introduced the 24576 byte limit on Ethereum mainnet smart contracts, however, other blockchains may not follow this standard, which I assume is why hardhat gives you the option to bypass the default Spurious Dragon limit.

Also, if you haven't already, try enabling the optimizer in your `hardhat.config.js`, this can decrease your contract size:

```js
solidity: {
    compilers: [
      {
        version: "0.8.7",
        settings: {
          optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 77,
          },
        },
      },
```